# Is there an antonym(...) for "append"?

Tags: word-request, antonyms, suffixes, prefixes

The [dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/append) says that the meaning of append is to attach something to the end of a document:

> **append**
>     [*uh*-pend]
>   **1.** to add as a supplement, accessory, or appendix; subjoin: to append a note to a letter.
>   **2.** to attach or suspend as a pendant.
>   **3.** to sign a document with; affix: to append one's signature to a will.

I'm asking in the prefix, suffix sense here, i.e. append to a word, not a document.

Also [here](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/16116-Antonym-of-Append) it says that "append" is not restricted to end or beginning, it just means "to attach":

> Append simply means "add to" or "attach to"; it's not restricted to adding something to the end of or after something else. An antonym for "append" would therefore be words such as "remove" or " detach, or any word that means "take away from".

So what would be the antonym(or converse, inverse, whichever fits best) for append in this case?
Also what will be the reverse of append, in terms of operation(like prefix is for suffix, which is just joining in the front instead of back)? I thought it would be [prepend](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prepend), but that had a different meaning.

Comment: I mean, I'm talking about appending to a word, not a document.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming

Answer (score 3):

If you remove something from the end of a word or a document, you [*truncate*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+truncate&oq=define+truncate) it.

The remaining part is said to be truncated.
The removed part is said to be discarded.

Truncation can be used more widely than just words, objects can be truncated by cutting off an extremity.

Comment: I've added to the question. I thought the meaning of the question was obvious, but didn't realize this.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. To be fair, this is the *antonym* of append.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial thought is correct.  The word is [*prepend*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+prepend).

The link that you give in the question does provide this definition in addition to the different definition that appears to be causing you confusion.

If you are adding an introductory section to the beginning of a document, you could also use [*preface*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=define+preface&oq=define+preface).

Comment: You need not have removed your earlier answer. *Truncate* would be a more obvious antonym to append than prepend would be. Prepend is using the opposite action to append, while truncate is reversing the action itself. So it's a more viable candidate for antonym. I was in a dilemma as to *what* to call it, I should have chosen inverse or something else.

Comment: I'll undelete it - leave you the option.

Comment: Is it possible to merge the answers? That would be better.